# Python Numpy Flat Function

Tags: python, numpy

How does the flat function in numpy work? Also, how do these indexes work? Please explain all the following code.

```
res = zeros((n, n), v.dtype)  
res[:n-k].flat[i::n+1] = v
```

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow! Would be nice you read about ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple use of `flat`:

```
In [410]: res = np.zeros((2,3), dtype=int)
In [411]: res
Out[411]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [413]: res.flat[::2]=1
In [414]: res
Out[414]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
In [415]: res.ravel()
Out[415]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

`flat` is a variant on `flatten` and `ravel`.  Here I use it to assign 1 to every other element of the flattened array.  You can see that happening in the `ravel` expression.  It's a bit less obvious in the 2d view of the same array.

In `res[:n-k].flat[i::n+1] = v`, the first `[:n-k]` selects some rows of `res`.  The `flat[]` acts in my example, assigning values from `v` to ever `n+1` element in the flattened array.

Again testing with a small example:

```
In [417]: res = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=int)
In [418]: res[:3]
Out[418]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [419]: res[:3].flat[2::6]
Out[419]: array([0, 0, 0])
In [420]: res[:3].flat[2::6]=[1,2,3]
In [421]: res
Out[421]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The use of `[i::n+1]` indexing ends up setting values on an diagonal.

or

```
In [422]: res = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=int)
In [424]: res.flat[0::6]
Out[424]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [425]: res.flat[0::6]=np.arange(5)
In [426]: res
Out[426]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4]])
```