# What is the significance of .flat in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How are these two codes different ? or there's no such difference at all ?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,4,5,5,6])
for item in a.flat:
    print(item)
```

**OR**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,4,5,5,6])
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

*Both gave same result*

```
1
2
4
5
5
6
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067174/python-numpy-flat-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property `.flat` will flatten an array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html

```
np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]).flat
>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

np.array([[[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]]]).flat
>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).flat
>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Because you are using an array that is already flat, the output will be the same for both pieces of code.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,4],[5,5,6]])
for item in a.flat:
    print(item)

>1
>2
>4
>5
>5
>6


import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,4],[5,5,6]])
for i in a:
    print(i)

>[1 2 4]
>[5 5 6]
```

Comment: Your `a = np.array([1,2,4,[5,5,6]])` gives me an `setting an array element with a sequence` error.  `np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4, [5]]])` is 1d object array.  `flat` does not change that.

Comment: `flat` on the regular 2d array looks better. :)

Comment: Somehow I just wasn't thinking as I was typing my answer :( it all just totally skipped my mind!